# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges triggering when stationary

Tags: swift, core-location

I have an application for a client that requires me to use the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` method however when I am stationary and haven't moved for a period of time, it will still trigger.

My location manager code is as below:

```
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = 1500
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

then my `didUpdateLocations`

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location: CLLocation = locations.last!
        print("Location: \(location)")

        print("SIGNIFICANT CHANGE")

    }
```

When I am travelling it prints every 1500ish metres as expected however it triggers when not expected and I am lost of a solution or probable problem.

Comment: Would activityType help? Since you are using it to travel, you could probably ignore walking or non automotive movements? If that is not an option, you could try figuring  in didUpdateLocations about the horizontal/vertical accuracy of your CLLocation object. ignore if it isn't within a threshold (this may lead to a few false negatives)

Comment: @NitinAlabur cheers I'll see how this goes and ill update you.

Comment: @NitinAlabur this ended up fixing the problem.

Comment: glad that helped. Posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `activityType` help?

Since you are using it to travel, you could probably ignore walking or non automotive movements?

If that is not an option, you could try figuring in `didUpdateLocations` about the horizontal/vertical accuracy of your CLLocation object. ignore if it isn't within a threshold (this may lead to a few false negatives)

Comment: Thanks. Weird it was still triggering without this but works now so oh well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't rely on `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()` to give you consistent results. If you go to an area with low cell tower density the distance you have to move before it gets triggered will change again. It's a low-power location method with low reliability.

That being said, it's unusual for it to trigger when you haven't moved. Maybe your device switched cell towers? Maybe it's a bug. File a report, make a small test project and send it in to Apple with your log files.

I don't know your requirements but one solution is to save (in an instance variable and as a file) the last found location and compare the distance between that and the new location to see if you've actually moved a long way. The other is to use region monitoring.

Comment: That was my problem. It's unusual for it to trigger. I do believe that it might be a cell tower change however it seems to be too constant for what's happening. I will investigate region monitoring and see if that suits the requirements. Thanks. Do you recommend submitting into apple too or just researching other methods?

Comment: @HarryJ Yes, I'd submit it to Apple. It seems unusual for it to trigger without movement.

Comment: Apple ended up not finding an issue with the code nor did they suggest a fix but `activityType` worked for the most part.

Comment: @HarryJ Good to know. Thanks for letting me know about this issue